# Permutation of a list with equals objects - Java

Tags: java, permutation

```
List<String> original = Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "C");
Collection<List<String>> permutations= Collections2.orderedPermutations(original)
```

gives

```
[A, B, C]
[A, C, B]
[B, A, C]
[B, C, A]
[C, A, B]
[C, B, A]
```

Great, now I have all possible permutations.
But let's say A and C are equal, their order does not matter when they are next to each other.

Wanted result:

```
[A, C, B] or [C, A, B]
[B, A, C] or [B, C, A]    
[A, B, C]
[C, B, A]
```

So we tried using a Comparator

```
    Collection<List<String>> permutations= Collections2.orderedPermutations(original, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
            if ((o1.equals("A") && o2.equals("C")) || (o2.equals("A") && o1.equals("C"))) {
                return 0;
            }
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```

But this gave us not the result we expected

```
[A, B, C]
[A, C, B]
```

Any suggestions how to get the wanted result? 
Although we used guava, any lib or custom solution is ok.

Comment: The problem is you are breaking the contract of the comparator. It should impose a complete and consistent ordering. Now A and C come before B (if you ask A) and after B (if you ask C). Don’t expect any consistent behaviour coming out of that.

Comment: If `A` and `C` are equal, isn't then `[A, B, C]` also equal to `[C, B, A]`?

Comment: If `A` and `C` be the same, then why not just write `A` for both of them?  Then you could use a set to remove any duplicate permutations.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the real story is a bit more complex. 
A,B,C stands for different promotions on a shopping cart. A has impact on article 1, C on article 2 and B on both. It doesn't mather if first A is applied and then C (or the other way around). Buth they both have to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to work. I have not tested.

```
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.equals("C")) o1 = "A";
        if (o2.equals("C")) o2 = "A";
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
```

Edit: added missing parenthesis

Comment: Muito obrigado, @João, for the fix

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove permutations that are logically equivalent, then I think you should start by writing out the actual 3-permutations as they would really appear if `A` and `C` were the same thing:

```
[A, B, A]
[A, A, B]
[B, A, A]
[B, A, A]
[A, A, B]
[A, B, A]
```

With duplicates removed, you would be left with this:

```
[A, B, A]
[A, A, B]
[B, A, A]
```

By using a `Set<List<String>>` you can keep the duplicates out, i.e.

```
List<String> original = Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "C");
Collection<List<String>> permutations = Collections2.orderedPermutations(original);

// now add your collection to a set to remove duplicates
Set<List<String>> permsNoDupes = new HashSet<>(permutations);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is in pair of ("A", "C") & ("C", "A") always put "A" first and transform it to ("A", "C")

```
    List<String> original = Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "C");
    Set<List<String>> permutations = Collections2.orderedPermutations(original).
            stream().
            map(list -> {
                int indexOfc = list.get(0) == "C" ? 0 : (list.get(1) == "C" ? 1 : -1);
                if (indexOfc != -1 && list.get(indexOfc + 1) == "A") {
                    // modifications not allowed on original list
                    list = new ArrayList<>(list); 
                    list.set(indexOfc, "A");
                    list.set(indexOfc + 1, "C");
                }
                return list;
            }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Results are

```
[[A, B, C], [C, B, A], [B, A, C], [A, C, B]]
```